# random sample n digits from range of (x,y) that average to mean k?

Tags: python, numpy, random

I am trying to random sample n=15 digits from range(low=3, high=7) that when summing the sampled 15 digits, they average to 5.

So far I've managed only to random sample n digits from certain range like:

```
n = 15
low  = 3
high = 8
range=[i for i in range(low,high)]
list =np.random.choice(range, n)
```

This generates random 15 digits of integers ranging from 3, 4, 5, 6, 7. However, I want it randomly sampled, yet the resulted average of the n digit sums equal 5? How can I go about this?

Comment: You cannot have both. If you take a random sample you will get a random average. You can come up with a process to get the numbers you want but it won't be a random sample. What do you need this for?

Comment: @jbch Thank you. Yeah, i realized it's not really random if I were to fix to certain average k. I'm trying to make random timing within given range, but the numbers to be somewhat fixed. I want to make sure the numbers are sampled around average k while I have random digits of 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 for later permutations of the list.

Comment: For clarification, I think the question can be refined to sample n digits from range(x,y) that average to mean k (So without random sampling)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this suits your needs but it's one way to do it.

```
import random

def kind_of_random(low, high, k, n):
    """
    Generate a list of n numbers between low and high
    with a mean of exactly k.
    """  
    assert k < high
    values = [low] * n
    to_add = (k - low) * n
    for _ in range(to_add):
        i = random.randint(0, n-1)
        # Don't want to add to a value that's already the max
        while values[i] == high:
            i = random.randint(0, n-1)
        values[i] += 1
    return values

ns = kind_of_random(3, 7, 5, 15)
```

I'm sure there are more efficient variations on this idea - I think you could do it faster by starting `n * [k]` instead of `n * [low]` and doing some number of paired add/substract operations, but this should be good enough for small `n`.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was thinking!!

Comment: It's not likely but technically the while loop could be infinite, it might be a better idea to replace `i = random.randint(0, n-1)` by `i += 1` under while loop to make sure it's not

Answer (score 1):

Well, we could use distribution which outcome naturally sums to known value, and
with fixed number of sampled numbers mean would be fixed as well.
Mean of 5 and number of samples to be 15 means total sum of number shall be always equal to 75.

Simplest one is [Multinomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution), so lets use it from NumPy. We set equal probabilities to 1/15, sample in the range [0...30] and reject sampling if any values is above desired range.

It is faster than method proposed by @jbch, no manual balance of sums and means, and distribution histogram is closer to symmetric if you care about it

Code

```
import numpy as np

def multiSum(n, p, maxv):
    while True:
        v  = np.random.multinomial(n, p, size=1)
        q  = v[0]
        a,  = np.where(q > maxv) # are there any values above max
        if len(a) == 0: # accept only samples below or equal to maxv
            return q

N = 15
p = np.full((N), 1.0/np.float64(N))

mean  = 5
start = 3
stop  = 7
n = N*mean - N*start

h = np.zeros((5), dtype=np.int64)
print(h)
for k in range(0, 10000):
    ns = multiSum(n, p, stop-start) + start # result in [3...7]
    #print(np.mean(ns))
    for v in ns:
        h[v-start] += 1

print(h)
```

Typical output histogram on my computer

```
[15698 38107 44584 33719 17892]
```

@jbch output histogram

```
[17239 39237 42188 28957 22379]
```